# jupyterhub failed to start

Tags: drivers, server, jupyter

hello everyone i installed jupyter in my cluster but it seems that cm-jupyterhub.service

cant start from the error that i got i think its about jupyter cant find its module file

can someone check with me because i dont know where to start to fix this

```
    systemctl status cm-jupyterhub.service
● cm-jupyterhub.service - JupyterHub
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cm-jupyterhub.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-05-18 13:28:26 CET; 15s ago
    Process: 2396653 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /cm/shared/apps/jupyter/14.2.1/bin/run.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2396653 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 18 13:28:26 omics-master bash[2396653]: +++ '[' -f /usr/share/modulefiles/StdEnv.lua ']'
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master bash[2396653]: +++ module --initial_load restore
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master bash[2396666]: ++++ /usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/lmod sh --initial_load restore
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master bash[2396666]: The system default contains no modules
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master bash[2396666]:   (env var: LMOD_SYSTEM_DEFAULT_MODULES is empty)
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master bash[2396666]:   No changes in loaded modules
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master bash[2396653]: +++ eval false
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master bash[2396653]: ++++ false
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master systemd[1]: cm-jupyterhub.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 18 13:28:26 omics-master systemd[1]: cm-jupyterhub.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```